# Launchscreen.storyboard SOMETIMES appear black?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit app where I stuck and jpg image to its LaunchScreen.storyboard and. I have this LaunchScreen.storyboard selected as my Launch Screen File under General > App Icon and Launch Images. When being tested on a device it works sometimes and other times it just appears black. Why is this happening? I have tried cleaning etc. I tried other solutions from similar questions but I still cant solve it. The thing that is bugging me is that its not consistent. Some advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using GIT go back to a version where this does not happen. And then search your way thru the history to find the exact commit very it happened.

Comment: I am not using git

Answer (score 0):

1)do make sure taking the image from the asset catalog. 
2)Changing the name from "logo3.png" to "logo3".
The above two step save my days.